# How to change backgroundcolour of all td elements in a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How is it possible to change the backgroundcolour of all td in a html table by JavaScript?

This was a try, but doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('AdressenTabelle').td.style.backgroundColor = "#white";
```

Here is the HTML for the table:

```
<table border="1" id="AdressenTabelle" class="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firma</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Straße</th>
        <th>Ort</th>
        <th>Rollen</th>
        <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="datatablecontent" onclick="doIt(event)">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There are many ways that this can be achieved (some are more efficient than others), can you show us an example of your HTML and tell us what environments you need to support?

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Valtos/RQQrw/

Comment: Why not change the background color of the `tbody` which has the `td`s?

Comment: Worth noting that @Manuel Richarz solution only works where [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is supported. (See Browser compatibility)

Comment: Nothing works, table didnt change the color

Comment: @Joofe Kopp My example and Manuel Richarz works fine in modern browser, this is the reason that I asked you for more information

Comment: I was wrong, Xotic750 s solution is working. i added the HTML code too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A further alternative on a modern browser

CSS

```
.myData {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="AdressenTabelle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td class="myData">Data one</td>
        <td class="myData">Data two</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
document.styleSheets[1].rules[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/nPJd4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("AdressenTabelle"); // Get the table
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {        // Iterate through all it's rows
    for (var j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {   // Iterate through the row's cells
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white';           // Set the colour. (No need for `#` on colour names)
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Xotic750: Overlooked the ID. That's something you could have seen and fixed in the fiddle yourself. [The code's fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/LvFtL/1/)

Comment: If I had noticed what your mistake was on your answer then I would have fixed it, I did go to the effort of creating 2 jsFiddles for you to make sure that you had supplied a working answer to the question. Glad that it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes painting the table instead of painting row by row is faster and works.

```
document.getElementById("AdressenTabelle").style.backgroundColor = 'white'
```

can do the trick